# App downloads files to storage even when permissions denied on Android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-download-manager

I'm building an Android app and I've got this weird bug where the app downloads a video into the Gallery even when permissions for storage are denied. I have read the documentation and I'm left puzzled by it. (As always with docs from google)

It says it's a `dangerous` permission, so it should ask me to allow it, but I don't think it did (This might just be my bad memory) but anyways, it's not allowed but it still can download videos to the gallery.

The permissions are in the AndroidManifest though.

minSdkVersion is 19 and target is 29.
phone is running Android 10

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is the code that downloads the file

```
 String filename = _filename + ".mp4";
            File direct =
                    new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                            .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "MY_FOLDER" + "/");
            if (!direct.exists()) {
                direct.mkdir();
            }

   DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uri);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                    .setTitle(filename)
                    .setMimeType("video/mp4")
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
                            File.separator + "MY_FOLDER" + File.separator + filename);
            dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Which Android version on used device?

Comment: Your app is not downloading and storing to file but the Downloadmanager does. The DownloadManager does not need permissions.

Comment: `direct.mkdir();` You do not have to create that directory as the DownloadManager will do it for you. Further you should check the return value as it can fail. `if(!direct.mkdir()) return;`

Comment: You should have told instead that you could create a directory with mkdirs(). But.. maybe you could not.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a possible security issue? Since you can download anything stored on the internet with DownloadManager, you could possibly easily download malicious software, could you not?

Comment: The code is copied from somewhere else, I'm not at all experienced in Android development :) Thanks for your comments